# Fill all empty inputs with value after clicking submit

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a form with different input types (text, radio buttons, select, text areas).
Form is table with button to add additional rows,

[image: how form looks]

My concern is that sometimes user doesn't fill all text inputs. If inputs are empty, on next step table that is generated from inserted values, skip empty table cells and messes output, like here for example:

[image: output]

Is it possible to add script in javascript/jquery that after clicking submit button it checks if there are empty inputs, and if so, put value, for example   or - or any other. 
I have added default value ( ), but sometimes user may remove white space by accident and it will mess output form. So with aditional "fail check" I will be 100% sure that all inputs are filled.
Making inputs required is not an option.

Thank you

Comment: Show us what code you have tried

Comment: "Is it possible". Yes.

Comment: Just have a `&nbsp;` after each field or prompt

Comment: Yes it's possible.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I validate this HTML/JavaScript form onsubmit?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18851684/how-do-i-validate-this-html-javascript-form-onsubmit)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  $("button").click(function(){
     $("form").find("input[type=text]").each(function(){
       if(!this.value)
         $(this).val("placeholder");
     });
  });
});
```

something like this should work for text inputs, just do the same for textareas if needed